# Trying to summarize JSON data with a stream: getting EMFILE error and "The process tried to write to a nonexistant pipe"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a large JSON file (~1 GB) that I am trying to work with. It is comprised of dates and cities. Ultimately my goal is to get an summary of the data: for each year, how many entries of each city do I have?

In the command window I run `type myjson.json |node --max-old-space-size=5120 script.js` where `script.js` is:

```
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream')
, es = require('event-stream'), fs = require('fs');


process.stdin
.pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))
.pipe(es.mapSync(function  (data) {

  if (data.date == '1972'){
           fs.createWriteStream('file_1972.txt');
          }    
    }
));
```

I am getting this error:

`Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'file_1972.txt' at Error (native)
The process tried to write to a nonexistant pipe.`

What is this error all about and how do I fix it? Is there something wrong in my approach / code?

Solution:

```
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream')
, es = require('event-stream'), fs = require('fs');

var stream1 = fs.createWriteStream('file_1972.txt'); 
process.stdin
.pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))
.pipe(es.mapSync(function  (data) {

  if (data.date == '1972'){
     stream1.write(data.date + data.city)
      }    
}
));
```

Comment: For each object that has a date `1972`, you're creating a file stream to `file_1972.txt` but don't do anything with it. So you're opening up the same file lots of times. If you have a reasonable amount of memory, you can quite easily gather the data you want in memory, and write it to a file once the JSON input has been fully read.

Comment: Thanksfor the help @robertklep, I fixed my code (& post).